# jmeter modify json GET result and use in PUT

Tags: javascript, json, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to automate some tests cases.  I have a JSON response from a GET, I want to change a single value of that JSON response and use the modified response in the body of a PUT.  The PUT needs all the same fields as the response, and I won't know what they all are, so I don't think the JSON Path Extractor will work in my case.  Efficiecy is a plus here, but I'll settle for something that just works.
I've tried this javascript in a BSF PostProcessor:

```
var response = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
var jsonOutput = JSON.parse(response);
jsonOutput.configState = "DELETED";
vars.put("json",jsonOutput);
```

But the Debug Sampler shows the response as an "Object" and nothing more.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: What's the inverse operation of `JSON.parse()`?`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you have `JSON` in Rhino or Nashorn, that's why your script is failing. I would suggest considering switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use [JSONBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) and [JSONSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString())
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
builder.content.configState = 'DELETED'
vars.put("json", builder.toPrettyString())
```

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article to learn about

- why JSR223 and Groovy is better than JavaScript
- how to add Groovy engine support to Jmeter
- scripting best practices